# How do I display a 24-Hour clock on my Mac login Screen?

Tags: macos, sonoma, mac-studio

I’m using a Mac Studio with OS Sonoma, so the previous answer(s) might not apply.
Does anyone know if I need to change Global Settings?
If so what is the command line?
Thanks!

Comment: What was it about [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/27988/100490) to [Can I show a 24-Hour clock on my Mac's Lock Screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27956/100490) that failed? Please [edit] and update your question to state why the other questions did not help. You say `the previous answer(s) might not apply`. did you try them? If so, what happened?

Comment: LOGIN screen does not equal LOCK screen. The 24 hour time format works on the LOCK screen but doesn't on the LOGIN screen in my case. I went to `System Settings` > `General` > `Date & Time` and checked both options `24-hour time` and `Show 24 hour time on Lock Screen`. OS version: `macOS Sonoma 14.3.1`

Answer (score 1):

For a 24-hour time to appear on the lock screen, you just have to go to **System Settings > General > Date & Time** and click the **24-hour time** option.

[image: Screenshot of the Settings Location]

Comment: This shows the 24 hour format on the LOCK screen but not on the LOGIN screen (right after the machine is started/booted up).